# How to pass a socks proxy to Socket.io client

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I would like to pass a socks proxy to my client-side Socket.io instance.
After an hour of googling I'm unabled to find atleast one tutorial about this.

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client'

const proxy = 'host:ip:username:password'
const socket = io('wss://example.com/')
socket.onAny((message) => {
  console.log(message)
})
```

I tried to pass a `SocksProxyAgent` to the io Manager `agent` from https://www.npmjs.com/package/socks-proxy-agent
But io Mananer is waiting for a `string` not `SocksProxyAgent`

I can't believe that the most popular websockets package doesn't support socks proxies, which are designed for websockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { HttpsProxyAgent } from 'https-proxy-agent'

const agent = HttpsProxyAgent('http://username:password@host:port')
const socket = io('wss://example.com/', { agent })
```